# Track click on jQuery created button

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a button on a button click and if this created button is also clicked there should be another action.

Here is my code:

```
//EDIT FUNCTION
            $('.edit').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                content = $(this).prop('name');
                id = $(this).prop('id');
                if(!document.getElementById('editnews')) {
                    jQuery('#edit').append('</br><textarea id="editnews" value="'+id+'"></textarea></br>');//is not shown, needed to stop, damn online lib
                    jQuery('#edit').append('<button name="'+id+'" class="saveedit btn btn-success btn-mini"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Save</button>');
                }
                $('#editnews').val(content);
            });

        // EDIT (SEND) FUNCTION
        $('.saveedit').on('click', function(e){
            console.log("oke");
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'index.php?page=news',
                data: {editid:$(this).prop('name'), editcontent:$('#editnews').val()}
            }).done(function(response) {
                location.reload();
            });
        });
```

So the first edit function works fine, but the second not as the button could not be tracked.
Hope you can help meh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **[`event-delegation`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** in order to bind event for dynamically created element

```
$('#edit').on('click','.saveedit', function(e){
    console.log("oke");
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index.php?page=news',
        data: {editid:$(this).prop('name'), editcontent:$('#editnews').val()}
    }).done(function(response) {
        location.reload();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not working because the event is attached to the `.saveedit` that is available in the DOM at the time when the script got executed. Any dynamically created `.saveedit` won't have this event attached.

What you have to do is attach the click event upon `document` i.e. handle it whenever any `.saveedit` is clicked that exists inside `document`:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.saveedit', function(e){
            console.log("oke");
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'index.php?page=news',
                data: {editid:$(this).prop('name'), editcontent:$('#editnews').val()}
            }).done(function(response) {
                location.reload();
            });
        });
```